# What are the methods for solving ODEs with accuracy higher than Runge Kutta 4?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computational-complexity, runge-kutta-methods

Usually, justification of using RK4 is the following: "RK4 demonstrates a better approximations than Euler and Modified Euler methods of solving ODEs and offers a good balance between accuracy and computation cost".

What are the other methods of solving ODEs that are more computationally expensive but offer a higher accuracy?

Comment: E.g. Higher Order Runge Kutta methods.

Comment: There are plenty of higher order RK methods. Surprisingly, the pattern for the number of steps per order changes after 4: it gets worse. So you start having diminishing returns. The higher order methods also have issues with double precision arithmetic.

Comment: By the way, classical RK4 is not used that much. Ode45 uses the Dormand-Price method which is a 4th order RK but not classical RK4.

Comment: See https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/ for a variety of RK methods different from RK4.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for instance [`DifferentialEquations.jl`](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/solvers/ode_solve/#Full-List-of-Methods) which has many relevant solvers implemented.